# Safari on iPhone folds out url bar when clicking links w/ return false;

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad, safari

I'm experiencing the weirdest problem. 
I've got a web site that i need to be consumable on iPhones (duh) that's acting out in Safari Mobile.

I've got a menu that slides contents depending on where you click, and it populates the DOM with various data that's pre-populated as JSON in a JavaScript variable. Thus there is no XHR/Ajax calls what so ever going on.

The problem is that whenever a link in the menu is clicked the address bar folds down and visualizes a progress bar - as if its loading something - even though i'm preventing default behavior and stops the propagation. I've double och triple checked that there's no network activity going on, but i really can't find out why the h*** it's behaving like that. Same problem is visualized on iPad/Safari, but i could live with that since it doesn't affect the viewport.

The binding of events is as simple as:

```
$('#menu a').on('click', function(e) {
    //do whatever...
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

The current iPhone i'm on has software version 6.1.4.

I've tried searching the net for something similar without any luck. 
Have you guys seen/heard about this behavior before?

What could be wrong? 
Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.
Found out that Safari will try to load all links that has urls in the href attribute.

Solution:

```
$('#menu a').attr('href', '#')
```